# While publishing the project using visual studio 2017 FTP it shows error

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment

While publishing the project using visual studio 2017.It's shown below mentioned error.How to solve this?Please, anyone, help me?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Copying file templates\upload-manager.file to
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\templates\upload-manager.file failed.
>   Could not find file 'templates\upload-manager.file'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into same issue because project files were added and removed so many times. Me just removed yellow marked file from visual studio solution & it worked fine for me.